# Append text from url tag in table column to textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html script with a form like this.

```
<table id="LinkData">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Web URL</th>
            <th>Point</th>
            <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-apricot.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Apricot'>Apricot</a></td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td><button id='edtData'>Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-avocado.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Avocado'></a>Avocado</td>
            <td>456</td>
            <td><button id='edtData'>Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-banana.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Banana'>Banana</a></td>
            <td>789</td>
            <td><button id='edtData'>Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-bilberry.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Bilberry'>Bilberry</a></td>
            <td>134</td>
            <td><button id='edtData'>Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-blackberry.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Blackberry'></a>Blackberry</td>
            <td>154</td>
            <td><button id='edtData'>Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id='crtList'>Crete List</button><br>
<textarea id='txtList' width='150px' height='200px'></textarea>
```

I need to take the existing text in a placeholder or url text of the column in the table to insert into the textarea that I have provided.

I need a javascript that can do so via click on the button **"Create List"**.
I try to do, but often only one text just appeared. I'm using javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#crtList", function(){
    var a = $("#frUrl");
    var i = -1;
    var myText = $("#txtList");
    while (++i < a.length) {
        if (a[i].href.indexOf("fruit") > 0) {
            var fr = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].getAttribute("placeholder"); 
        }
    }
    myText.append(fr + ", ")
});
```

I need to copy all the text in  tag into the textarea. I want results might look like this:

```
Apricot, Avocado, Banana, Bilberry, Blackberry,
```

thanks for your help and for your reference.

Comment: Please provide your `javascript` code.

Comment: $(document).on("click", "#crtList", function(){
 var a = $("#frUrl");
 var i = -1;
 var myText = $("#txtList");
 while (++i < a.length) {
  if (a[i].href.indexOf("fruit") > 0) {
   var fr = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].getAttribute("placeholder"); 
  }
 }
 myText.append(fr + ", ")
});

Comment: So do you want the Url href value or the placeholder value?

Comment: I have placeholder value only, cause I'm set same value from placeholder and url text in <a>. thanks

Comment: Okay, so the text area should essentially show up like you stated above?
Apricot, Avocado, Banana, Bilberry, Blackberry,

Comment: You have errors in your HTML. 1) <a> elements do not have placeholder attributes, and 2) you have duplicate IDs; the latter is the direct cause of `$("#frUrl");` not working. Now the answers are showing you ways to work around the errors, but it's still a terrible idea to keep them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm understanding in your post, this is the JS/jQuery you are looking for:

```
var totalLength = $('*[id*="frUrl"]').length;

$('#crtList').click(function() {
  $('*[id*="frUrl"]').each(function(index) {
    if (index === totalLength - 1) {
      $('#txtList').append($(this).attr('placeholder') + '.');
    } else {
      $('#txtList').append($(this).attr('placeholder') + ', ');
    }
  });
});
```

This takes all of the placeholder values after clicking the 'Create List' button and appends them to the specified list. In addition, the values are comma separated and a period is added to the last item in the list.

Comment: @Fhahry no problem. I learned a bit along the way figuring it out so it was a win-win. Good luck with the rest of this project!

Answer (score 0):

First, duplicate id isn't good way to bound your data.So I set the attribute `class` editBtn replace with id of button.I just show off the class and your problem is solved that I provide sample code for you.

**Code HTML**

```
<html>
<table id="LinkData">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Web URL</th>
            <th>Point</th>
            <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-apricot.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Apricot'>Apricot</a></td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td><button id='edtData' class='editBtn'>Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-avocado.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Avocado'></a>Avocado</td>
            <td>456</td>
            <td><button id='edtData' class="editBtn">Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-banana.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Banana'>Banana</a></td>
            <td>789</td>
            <td><button id='edtData' class="editBtn">Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-bilberry.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Bilberry'>Bilberry</a></td>
            <td>134</td>
            <td><button id='edtData' class="editBtn">Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-blackberry.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Blackberry'></a>Blackberry</td>
            <td>154</td>
            <td><button id='edtData' class="editBtn">Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id='crtList'>Crete List</button><br>
<textarea id='txtList' width='150px' height='200px'></textarea>

</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT WITH JQUERY**

```
$(function () {
  let $edit = $(".editBtn");
  let $textarea = $(".editBtn");
  $(".editBtn").on("click", function () {
    let href = $(this).parent().parent().children().find("a").attr("href");
    $(".editBtn").text(href);
  });
})
```

If you want to edit pure javascript, it's a time consuming and out dated.
Final, Don't forget add the jquery lib in your script.

**fixed code**

I miss the last paragram.set `each` to implement.

**Html**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><!doctype>
<html>
<table id="LinkData">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Web URL</th>
            <th>Point</th>
            <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="mainData">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-apricot.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Apricot'>Apricot</a></td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td><button id='edtData' class='editBtn'>Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-avocado.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Avocado'></a>Avocado</td>
            <td>456</td>
            <td><button id='edtData' class="editBtn">Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-banana.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Banana'>Banana</a></td>
            <td>789</td>
            <td><button id='edtData' class="editBtn">Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-bilberry.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Bilberry'>Bilberry</a></td>
            <td>134</td>
            <td><button id='edtData' class="editBtn">Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><a href='http://fruit-blackberry.fr' id='frUrl' placeholder='Blackberry'></a>Blackberry</td>
            <td>154</td>
            <td><button id='edtData' class="editBtn">Edit</button> | <button id='delData'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id='crtList'>Crete List</button><br>
<textarea id='txtList' width='150px' height='200px'></textarea>

</html>
```

**javascrip**

```
$(function () {
  let $edit = $(".editBtn");
  let $textarea = $(".editBtn");
  $(".editBtn").on("click", function () {
    let href = $(this).parent().parent().children().find("a").attr("href");
    $(".editBtn").text(href);
  });
  $("#crtList").on("click", function () {
    $("#mainData").children().each(function () {
      let href = $(this).find("a").attr("placeholder");
      let text = $("#txtList").text();
      $("#txtList").text(text + " " + href);
    });
  })

})
```

Comment: It's work, thanks. But I have to copy text from placeholder value to texarea with #crtList clik button. So, I have result like: Apricot, Avocado, Banana, Bilberry, Blackberry,  in textarea(#txtList). my script only copy 1 result from 1 url.

Comment: I fixed the placeholder `attr("placeholder")`,I ignored your need.

Comment: In fact we need to bind the data from your javascript and then append on your table.This situation would happened on crawler.